# Como converter uma resposta em JSON para um objeto em C#?

Tags: c#, json, desserialização

Estou fazendo um request e recebendo um JSON como este:

```
{
  "id": "1000000000000000", 
  "name": "BrunoLM", 
  "first_name": "Bruno", 
  "last_name": "X", 
  "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/340760/brunolm", 
  "username": "brunolm", 
  "bio": "...",
  "gender": "male", 
  "timezone": -2, 
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Mas nem sempre o servidor envia todos estes campos, as vezes pode vir sem `locale`, ou `link`...

Gostaria de converter isto para um objeto e poder acessar por propriedades:

```
objeto.name      // ou objeto.Name
objeto.last_name // ou objeto.LastName
```

Como fazer isso? O que é mais recomendado?

Se a opção mais recomendada for utilizar alguma *library* fica uma pergunta de curiosidade: é possível fazer utilizando apenas o que o .NET oferece?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Te recomendo o uso do [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

Veja o exemplo da [Documentação](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

Comment: Caso você não tenha uma classe para mapear o `Json` você pode utilizar como `dynamic`. Exemplo: `dynamic deserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializado);` e acessar as propriedades como `deserializado.Name`.

Answer (score 7):

Para fazer isso sem usar nenhuma biblioteca externa, você pode se aproveitar do fato que JSON é um subconjunto de JavaScript, e utilizar o `JavaScriptSerializer` a partir do `System.Web.Extensions.dll` (.NET 3.5 SP1):

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(input);
```

Como o resultado é um `Dictionary`, a falta de algum campo não prejudicará o resultado.

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402694/520779) no SO em inglês, também é possível se definir uma classe/conjunto de classes para receber um resultado - em vez de um `Dictionary` - de modo que você possa acessar as propriedades da forma como você prefere. Só não sei como ele se comportaria com campos faltando, teria que fazer um teste.

Código de exemplo da pergunta acima:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public class NameTypePair
{
    public string OBJECT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string OBJECT_TYPE { get; set; }
}
public enum PositionType { none, point }
public class Ref
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
public class SubObject
{
    public NameTypePair attributes { get; set; }
    public Position position { get; set; }
}
public class Position
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { objects = new List<SubObject>(); }
    public string displayFieldName { get; set; }
    public NameTypePair fieldAliases { get; set; }
    public PositionType positionType { get; set; }
    public Ref reference { get; set; }
    public List<SubObject> objects { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{

    const string json = @"{
  ""displayFieldName"" : ""OBJECT_NAME"", 
  ""fieldAliases"" : {
    ""OBJECT_NAME"" : ""OBJECT_NAME"", 
    ""OBJECT_TYPE"" : ""OBJECT_TYPE""
  }, 
  ""positionType"" : ""point"", 
  ""reference"" : {
    ""id"" : 1111
  }, 
  ""objects"" : [
    {
      ""attributes"" : {
        ""OBJECT_NAME"" : ""test name"", 
        ""OBJECT_TYPE"" : ""test type""
      }, 
      ""position"" : 
      {
        ""x"" : 5, 
        ""y"" : 7
      }
    }
  ]
}";

    static void Main()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Foo foo = ser.Deserialize<Foo>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o método [`Json.Decode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) (parte do ASP.NET MVC) para obter um objeto dinâmico com as propriedades do JSON:

```
dynamic pessoa = Json.Decode(json);

Console.WriteLine(pessoa.name);
```

E se você tem uma classe com as mesmas propriedades do JSON, pode usar [`Json.Decode<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547931%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) para obter uma instância do objeto desejado:

```
Pessoa pessoa = Json.Decode<Pessoa>(json);

Console.WriteLine(pessoa.name);
```

Answer (score 5):

### Fluent URL Http

Existe um componente chamado [Fluent URL Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) muito  bacana para fazer toda essa tarefa de realizar um *request* e receber um objeto já desserializado.

Primeiro instale o pacote no seu projeto usando o [NuGet Package Flurl.](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl/).

> PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http

Depois, basta consumir e fazer requests da forma mais elegante que já vi:

```
var result = await "https://api.mysite.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("person") // https://api.mysite.com/person
    .SetQueryParams(new { a = 1, b = 2 }) // https://api.mysite.com/person?a=1&b=2
    .WithOAuthBearerToken("my_oauth_token")
    .PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = "Frank", last_name = "Underwood" }) // { "first_name": "Frank", "last_name": "Underwook" }
    .ReceiveJson<T>();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Utilizando dynamic

É possível estender um `DynamicObject` para obter os valores da seguinte maneira:

```
public class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        this.Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this.Dictionary[binder.Name];

        if (result is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new DynamicJsonObject(result as IDictionary<string, object>);
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList && (result as ArrayList) is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new List<DynamicJsonObject>((result as ArrayList).ToArray().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x as IDictionary<string, object>)));
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList)
        {
            result = new List<object>((result as ArrayList).ToArray());
        }

        // nunca lança exceção se não encontrar o valor
        return true;
        // this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
    }
}
```

E estender o `JavaScriptConverter` para obter os valores

```
public class DynamicJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        if (type == typeof(object))
        {
            return new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(object) })); }
    }
}
```

E para utilizar

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jss.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

dynamic json = jss.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(object));
```

Desta forma é possível acessar dinamicamente os valores do objeto.

```
json.name
json.id
// ...
```

Poderia modificar o método `TrySetMember` do `DynamicJsonObject` para que se pudesse modificar os valores do objeto. Do modo demonstrado serve apenas como leitura.

Answer (score 2):

### DataContractJsonSerializer

Existem também o `DataContractJsonSerializer`, que requer que as propriedades de uma classe tenha o atributo `[DataMember]`.

Esta classe pode ser serializada com o `DataContractJsonSerializer`, mas a propriedade `ID` não será incluída.

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "número")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Desta forma pode-se utilizar

```
var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestClass));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    js.WriteObject(ms, new TestClass { ID = 1, Number = 55 });

    // {"número":55}
    string jsonSerializado = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    ms.Position = 0;

    // new TestClass { ID = 0, Number = 55 }
    var jsonDeserealizado = (TestClass)js.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
return Json(new { id= "1000000000000000", name= "BrunoLM", first_name= "Bruno", last_name= "X", link= "http://stackoverflow.com/users/340760/brunolm", username= "brunolm", bio= "...", gender= "male", timezone= -2, locale "en_US" });
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que esse código faz?