# Desserialização Json com DataContractJsonSerializer Null Pointer Exception

Tags: c#, json, uwp, desserialização

A princípio estou fazendo um teste se consigo me comunicar direito com a API do Wikipedia. Meu primeiro objetivo é pegar dados da API, transformá-los em objeto e apresentar alguma coisa na tela que demonstre que esse processo está correto.

Criei um pacote chamado WikipediaViewer e nele coloquei uma classe chamada WikipediaMapProxy, que possui um método cujo objetivo é fazer a requisição, pegar o json e transformá-lo em um objeto c#. Além disso, dentro do pacote WikipediaViewer pus várias classes que servirão para serem utilizadas na criação do objeto, resultante de json.

**Minhas dúvidas:**

**1) Na minha MainPage.xaml.cs, está dando um null pointer na linha 33:**

https://github.com/raulfmiranda/csharp/blob/master/WikipediaViewer/WikipediaViewer/MainPage.xaml.cs

Isso significa que está ocorrendo algum problema na hora de pegar o json e transformá-lo para objeto. Em WikipediaMapProxy, estou usando a classe DataContractJsonSerializer que faz o trabalho de transformar o json no objeto C#. Por isso coloquei [DataContract] em cima de cada classe e [DataMember] em cima de cada propriedade, para informar ao DataContractJsonSerializer como ele deve fazer essa transformação. Entretanto, os nomes dos atributos não estão exatamente como está no json. Por exemplo, no json, não existe um Item, porque lá eles são nomeados por uma numeração, mas eu resolvi chamar de item. Além disso, a classe Pages era para conter vários itens, por isso, pus uma lista de itens dentro. Não sei se isso está correto.

**2) Existe um probleminha na linha 23:**
https://github.com/raulfmiranda/csharp/blob/master/WikipediaViewer/WikipediaViewer/WikipediaMapProxy.cs#L23

Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() recebe uma string como parâmetro, mas, se eu colocar apenas result como parâmetro, o compilador informa que não pode fazer uma conversão implícita de um Task para uma string, por isso que eu resolvi colocar como parâmetro result.Result, mas não sei se isso está correto. O que acha?

Veja o Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WikipediaViewer
{
    public class WikipediaMapProxy
    {
        public async static Task<RootObject> GetResult(string searchedString)
        {
            string jsonSource = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=2&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=gandhi&origin=*";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var response = await http.GetAsync(jsonSource);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Result));
            var data = (RootObject) serializer.ReadObject(ms);

            return data;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Thumbnail
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string source { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int width { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Item
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int pageid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ns { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int index { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string pageimage { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string extract { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Pages
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Item>  item { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Query
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Pages pages { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Query query { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Devo lembrar de ler este post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/706/como-converter-uma-resposta-em-json-para-um-objeto-em-c?rq=1

Comment: Acho que encontrei a resposta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555627/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-parse-json-objects-that-are-dynamically-named/41555809#41555809