# Como que faria para converter esse Json em Objetos no C#

Tags: c#, json, conversão, microsoft, dotnet-cli

Como converter esse JSON para um objeto C#?

```
{
   "Maquinas":{
      "Maquina1":[
         {
            "comando":"Get",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.254.221",
            "port":"3000",
            "usuario":"teste",
            "Senha":"123456"
         },
         {
            "comando":"sendFuncionarios",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.140.221",
            "port":"3000",
            "usuario":"teste fabrica",
            "Senha":"111111",
            "funcionariosHA":[
               {
                  "nome":"Daril Mont",
                  "pis":"1234567891",
                  "verdigital":false,
                  "codigo":30
               },
               {
                  "nome":"Mont Daril",
                  "pis":"62633975303",
                  "verdigital":true,
                  "codigo":31
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "comando":"sendEmpresa",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.140.221",
            "port":"3000",
            "usuario":"fabrica",
            "Senha":"123456",
            "EmpresaHexaAdv":[
               {
                  "razaoSocial":"Oficina de Computadores",
                  "tipoCadastro":"CNPJ",
                  "CPF":"",
                  "CNPJ":"20330852471",
                  "endereco":"R. Mariana, 265",
                  "CEI":""
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "Maquina2":[
         {
            "comando":"Get",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.210.223",
            "port":"51000",
            "cpf":"13556285630"
         },
         {
            "comando":"sendFuncionarios",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.210.223",
            "port":"51000",
            "cpf":"13556285630",
            "funcionariosInnerREP":[
               {
                  "nome":"Dorval Miguel",
                  "pis":"1234567891",
                  "verdigital":false,
                  "codigo":30,
                  "senha":"0030"
               },
               {
                  "nome":"Leticia do Carmo",
                  "pis":"62633975303",
                  "verdigital":true,
                  "codigo":31,
                  "senha":"0031"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "comando":"sendEmpresa",
            "enderecoip":"192.168.210.223",
            "port":"51000",
            "cpf":"13556285630",
            "EmpresaInnerREP":[
               {
                  "razaoSocial":"Oficina de Computadores",
                  "tipoCadastro":"CNPJ",
                  "CPF":"",
                  "CNPJ":"20330852471",
                  "endereco":"Rua abacate 25",
                  "CEI":""
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: sua pergunta ja foi respondida aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/706/como-converter-uma-resposta-em-json-para-um-objeto-em-c

Comment: @VictorWillian `Maquinas` só terá dois atributos `Maquina1` e `Maquina2` se esse número pode variar terá que mudar seu Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma fácil de você criar um classe que represente um Json (na Dotnet 4.5 ou superior) é copiar o conteúdo Json para a área de transferência, criar uma nova classe e utilizar o comando do menu **Edit > Paste Especial > Paste JSON as Classes**. A IDE automaticamente criará uma ou mais classes que represente sua estrutura JSON.

Tendo essa classe você facilmente pode Deserializar uma string JSON em uma instância dessa classe utilizando [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Veja um Exemplo:

```
public static MeuObjeto Deserializar(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeuObjeto>(json);
    }
```